Chord from tangent points perpendicular to another tangent point
The question was sent from my students for olympiad preparation.

Let $O$ be an inscribed circle of triangle $ABC$, which tangents to $AB, AC$, and $BC$ at $D, E$, and $F$, respectively. If $P$ is a point on $DE$ such that $FP$ is perpendicular to $DE$. Prove that $\angle DBP = \angle ECP$.

I attempted to prove $\angle BPF = \angle FPC$ but still had no clue. I think that $PF$ should be some sense of normal line in which BP and PC are incidence rays.

Thank you for your help, I noticed that I mistyped the problem.

Hi! To avoid down-votes and close-votes, please provide us some context for this question, such as: (a) Is this homework? (b) If so, what course are you taking? (c) What specific topic are you covering at the moment? (d) What do you know that you think might be connected? (e) If you're stuck, what are you stuck on? For example, do you know what to apply, but don't know how to apply it, or do you not know what to apply? Please [edit] these facts into your original post, not as responses to this comment, as comments may be deleted without warning.

Show us your efforts and ask specifically where you have doubts or are stuck.

Hint: if $(X,F;B,C) = -1$, and $\angle XPF = 90^\circ$, then PF and PX are angle bisectors of $\angle BPC$

Since there is no effort shown, I can only provide hints to the solution.
(0). Basic knowledge required. (0.1) OD = OF = r = the in-radius; (0.2) By tangent properties, BD = BF and CE = CF.

(1) Show that $\triangle DPF \sim \triangle OFC$. Hence, obtain the corresponding ratio pairs.
(2) Similarly, obtain the ratio pairs from $\triangle BOF$ and $\triangle FEP$.
(3) What is the relation between $\triangle BOF$ and $\triangle BOD$
(4) After simplifying the combined ratios thus obtained, you should have $\dfrac {BD}{DP} = \dfrac {CE}{EP}$
(5) Show that $\triangle BDP \sim \triangle CEP$.
(6) …..
